# updating a dict inside a list

Tags: list, dictionary, data-structures, tcl

I have the following data structure in TCL (list of dicts)

list [{1 a 2 b} {1 c 2 d} {1 e 2 d}]

as you can see there are three dicts with the same keys inside a list.

I want to update d with, lets say P only of e is there, else construct the dict {1 e 2 P} and append to the list.

Whether, I update or append, at the end I should have this

list [{1 a 2 b} {1 c 2 d} {1 e 2 P}]

I know I can iterate and achieve this, but that seems ugly. is there any shorter method to do this. I am not very familiar with TCL advanced dict commands, so any help much appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1 :**

```
% set input
{1 a 2 b} {1 c 2 d} {1 e 2 d}
% #index 2 3 points to 'd' 
% lset x 2 3 P
{1 a 2 b} {1 c 2 d} {1 e 2 P}
%
```

**Approach 2 :**

```
% set input {{1 a 2 b} {1 c 2 d} {1 e 2 d}}
{1 a 2 b} {1 c 2 d} {1 e 2 d}
% #The element to search and replace...
% set elem {1 e 2 d}
1 e 2 d
%
% lset input [lsearch $input $elem] [dict replace $elem 2 P]
{1 a 2 b} {1 c 2 d} {1 e 2 P}
%
```

Comment: thanks, but no, I cannot do that, because I can only search by 1 e, so the elem can only be {1 e}, as I would not know the value for key 2, ( which is d in the example). any other way ?

Comment: If you know only the  element `1 e`, then how you are planning to replace ? If suppose, that the dict is having multiple elements, then what would you do ? Say, `{1 e 7 m 2 d}` or `{1 e 2 d 4 f}`.  ?

Comment: this dict will only ever have two keys. (1 and 2). thanks

Comment: why question is in dict, is there a way to replace the value of a two valued-dict  based on the value of the other.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use `lmap` to iterate over the list, conditionally doing the dictionary transform and setting a flag if it ever gets done. Then, if there was no such change done, append the new dictionary at the end.

```
set input {{1 a 2 b} {1 c 2 d} {1 e 2 d}}

set replaced 0
set output [lmap d $input {
    if {[dict exists $d 1] && [dict get $d 1] eq "e"} {
        set replaced 1
        dict set d 2 "P"
    }
    set d
}]
if {!$replaced} {
    lappend output [dict create 1 e 2 "P"]
}
```

If you're using 8.5, you can use `foreach` and `lappend` instead of `lmap`. The code is a bit longer if you do.

Comment: thanks. I hv done something similar. but looking for something much more simpler if there is one.

Comment: @lollahmullah Can't think of one; nobody's done a system for doing operations that take complicated coordinates inside of values since it isn't something that's a very common requirement in practice.